# Xdebug xdebug.mode = debug not working for me

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7.4, xdebug-3

I have installed Xdebug on a Ubuntu 20.04 system.  I followed [this documentation](https://medium.com/@s73obrien/setting-up-vs-code-to-develop-through-ssh-remotely-can-be-a-bit-intimidating-but-you-can-do-it-c4e9b2b42190) , which I found to be quite well written, and got everything installed per the specs. (I used apt rather than yum, and placed the .so file into `/usr/lib/php/20190902` folder rather than the document's example.)

In that document, there is a reference to adding to the php.ini file (I added to `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` files).  Since the article doesn't specifically mention "sections" of the .ini file, I put them within the `[PHP]` section.  (This is consistent with the remark about putting right before the Quick Reference bit.)  I restarted Apache2 and the `phpinfo()` output now includes Xdebug, which it did not include before.  All well and good.

The trouble I'm having is that although I set `xdebug.mode = debug` in the php.ini files, the `phpinfo()` output tells me that `xdebug.mode` is set to `develop`.  Consequently, Step debugger shows as Disabled in my configuration.  I cannot see why.

These are the lines I've added to each of those php.ini files:

```ini
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

And here are the key excerpts from the `phpinfo()` output:

[image: Xdebug settings 1]

[image: Xdebug settings 2]

On a whim, I tried placing all of those settings also within a new section of php.ini which I called `[xdebug]`.  When that didn't work, I tried `[Xdebug]`.  I restarted Apache2 after each attempt, but the symptom never changed.

What might I be missing?

Comment: `zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so` (that has an extra `"`). In any case, it is very likely that there is either another `xdebug.mode` line somewhere, or a different `ini` file is being used. Try to see what the output of `xdebug_info()` tells you — it also mentions which INI files have been read.

Comment: You nailed it @Derick!  I just fixed that line that I'd looked at a hundred times - and restarted apache - all is well! Woo hoo!   Thank you so much; my eyes must be too tired.  To answer your question, I ran 'grep xdebug /etc/php/7.4' and found that xdebug was mentioned in several places - all with the values I want.  Only that one line was wrong (lacking a closing quote)

Comment: I meant, grep -r xdebug /etc/php/7.4  ... all the ini files read by php were in subfolders there.

Comment: Added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so` (that has an extra `"`).

In any case, it is very likely that there is either another `xdebug.mode` line somewhere, or a different INI file is being used. Try to see what the output of `xdebug_info()` tells you — it also mentions which INI files have been read.

Answer (score -1):

I'm here to help anyone with Xdebug on a Windows system and PHP 7.4 installed.
Can try to set the php.ini as shown below.
Can see my xdebug extension is called php_xdebug.dll inside this folder C:\xampp\php\ext\

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.stopOnEntry = true
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.output_dir ="c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.log = "C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

*Extras for the visual studio code user. Make sure the port inside the configuration is the same as the one that you set.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9000,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The question clearly stated that the problem occurred on a Ubuntu system.  But thanks for the post.

Comment: Even though the answer is irrelevant in the context of this question. It helped in my case. thanks!